# How to operate txt file on PHP?

Tags: php

I have txt file, which keeps 1 as in the following query to take the contents from txt and +1

```
 function analitic(){

    $file = fopen(TEMPLATEPATH . "/analitic.txt", "w");
    $txt = $_POST['data']; //$txt = 1                           
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);

 }
```

And how to add a date in the txt file? And if the date is different, save the data in the next line?

Thank you google translate :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work...

```
file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH."/analitic.txt",PHP_EOL.date('c').PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
```

- PHP_EOL - this the "next line" character
- file_put_contents / FILE_APPEND is a slightly more concise method of writing to a file
- 'c' - is the date format for an ISO date time, please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more information

Comment: Thanks! And how to take the value from the txt file and tot up a different value?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand anything else from your question :(  If you can edit to make it clearer I might update my answer.

Comment: its ok, i'm find answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Some think like this:

```
function my_action_myFunc(){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $date = date('d.m.Y');
    $file = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH."/analitic.txt",null,null, 10);
    settype($file, "integer");
    settype($data, "integer");
    $a = $file+$data;
    file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH."/analitic.txt",$date.PHP_EOL.$a);
    wp_die();
}
```